# Extract table data from website using Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get information related to any website the user is trying to access. To stop any malicious website access, I need details like blacklist status, IP address, Location of server etc. I got this from URLVOID website. < https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/>

I am getting following results in a table format and trying to fetch the same in spyder. 
[See the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b5ZL.png)

I am using regex approach to get particulars from the table.

```
######

import httplib2 
import re
def urlvoid(urlInput):                
    h2 = httplib2.Http(".cache")
    resp, content2 = h2.request(("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + urlInput), "GET")
    content2String = (str(content2))
    rpderr = re.compile('\<div\sclass\=\"error\"\>', re.IGNORECASE)
    rpdFinderr = re.findall(rpderr,content2String)
    if "error" in str(rpdFinderr):
        ipvoidErr = True
    else:
        ipvoidErr = False
    if ipvoidErr == False:

        rpd2 = re.compile('(?<=Server Location</span></td><td>)[a-zA-Z0-9.]+(?=</td></tr>)')
        rpdFind2 = re.findall(rpd2,content2String)
        rpdSorted2=sorted(rpdFind2)

    return rpdSorted2

urlvoid("google.com")
######
```

However, it is not much efficient and this regex does not work with all the websites. Is there any simpler way to get all this information?

Comment: If you use `bs4`. the job can be done faster and easier. Also you dont need selenium in this site.

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest you to scrape data with regex because it can be done by `bs4`, and if you build up a regex to complete that you need long time and complex condition.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
import re

def urlvoid(urlInput):
    url = "https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + urlInput
    res = requests.get(url)
    text = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml").find("table",class_="table table-custom table-striped")
    all_tr = soup.find_all("tr")
    value = { tr.find_all("td")[0].text : 
                tr.find_all("td")[1].text.replace("\xa0","")
                for tr in all_tr}
    print(value)

urlvoid("google.com")
```